# Getting value from a checkbox in a datatable

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a data table that I'm writing checkboxes next to every row. However, when I submit the page nothing is passed to my method. Any help is appreciated! My code is below

Model:

```
foreach (int analysis in ChemList.Select(d => d.analysisId).Distinct())
        {
            DataRow dr = GridData.NewRow();
            GridData.Rows.Add(dr);
            GridData.Rows[gridrow][0] = "<input type='checkbox' value="+checknum+"    checked>";
            GridData.Rows[gridrow][1] = ChemList[listrow].analysisId;
            GridData.Rows[gridrow][2] = ChemList[listrow].analysisTime;
            GridData.Rows[gridrow][3] = ChemList[listrow].sampleType;
            GridData.Rows[gridrow][4] = ChemList[listrow].productId;
```

Template that ensures the checkbox is written:

```
@using System;
@model TheManhattanProject.Models.CellValueViewModel
<td>
@{if(Model.Value.StartsWith("<input type='checkbox'"))
{

        @Html.Raw(Model.Value);

}
else
{

        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Value);

}
}
</td>
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Average", "Home", "POST"))
{
<input type="submit" value="Average" />
<div id="grid">
    <table id="example"  class ="gridTable">
        <thead class="gridHead">
            <tr>
              @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Columns)
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Rows)
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
}
```

Controller Method (just a placeholder, but the values stay null):

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Average(params int[] values)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: have you stepped thru the code ..? if so can you see any values while stepping thru..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Controller will take whatever you expect it to normally take and a `FormCollection collection` and get the checkbox by it's `name` attribute: `collection["checkBoxName"]`